# How to find/edit the DOM of jQuery Tooltipster

Tags: jquery, tooltipster

Using jQuery Tooltipster extension I made an in line tool-tip like so:

```
<span class="tooltip" data-tooltip-content="#tooltip_content">This span has a tooltip with HTML when you hover over it!</span>

<div class="tooltip_templates">
    <span id="tooltip_content">
        <img src="myimage.png" />
        <strong>This is the content of my tooltip!</strong>
    </span>
</div>
```

But as soon as I hover over the tooltip the first time the html is removed from the "tooltip_templates". It is then appended to end of page but only when hovering. This is a problem because I at times need to edit the content of the tool-tip when fields are updated via Ajax, but I can not find elements inside a tool-tip with jQuery because it does not appear to be in the DOM anywhere after the first time the tool-tip is used. Any ideas how to edit the tool-tip DOM or keep the tool-tip html in the DOM so it can be found? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The content of the tooltip can be accessed at any time with the `content` method.

Comment: Good point. But that sounds complicated because I would have to load every tool tip and look in its DOM to see if it has a field that has changed. And since I have a good number of Ajax calls that could need to update fields and a good number of tool tips keeping them all checking all the others might be difficult to maintain.

Comment: Just have the tooltips clone your html every time they open then, using the functionBefore and content methods.